# First row first column data in the table is missing in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]

View

```
@model SimpleEmpCRUD.Models.CommonViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddEmployeeDetails";
}

<table id="empTable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var Emp in Model.EmpResultSet)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Emp.EId</td>
                <td>@Emp.FirstName</td>
                <td>@Emp.LastName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
public class EmployeesController : Controller
    {
        //Add Employee
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddEmployeeDetails()
        {
            EmployeeDBHandler emp = new EmployeeDBHandler();
            CommonViewModel model = new CommonViewModel();             
            model.EmpResultSet = new List<Employee>();
            model.EmpResultSet = emp.GetEmployees();          
            model.CitySet = new Cities();
            model.CitySet.CityList = emp.FetchAllCities();
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Handler

```
 public class EmployeeDBHandler
    {
        public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
            string sqlConnstr = Utils.GetDBConnection();
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnstr);
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllEmployee", sqlConn);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlConn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
            { 
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var emp = new Employee()
                    {
                        EId = (int)(reader["EmpID"]),
                        FirstName = (reader["FirstName"].ToString()),
                        LastName = (reader["LastName"].ToString())
                    };
                    empList.Add(emp);
                }
            }
            return empList;
        }
```

Why the value 1 fail to appear in the table as seen in the attached image. Id,First Name and Last Name values brought into the view and every datas shown in the table except the first row, first column.

I think I'm missing something obvious here..Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: please kindly share your code.

Comment: It looks like css issue. Can you provide fiddle with the issue?

Comment: Have you checked that the model actually contains a value for that field? What did you expect it to say?

Comment: @SamuelAkosile Update the question with code

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota even I thought the same.. but couldn't found out.

Comment: @ADyson yes, model contains a value. Have a look at it the updated question.

Comment: Ok thanks, you've shown how you assign the value. But still that doesn't prove that a value actually exists. For that we would need to look in the database rows.

Answer (score 0):

We have to validate 2 types of code by which this problem is occuring :

```
1)Code Side

2)Design Side (css)
```

1) Code Side: Always handle null  ( `.ToString() cannot handle null values . So use Convert.ToString() insterad of that`)

Updated Code:

```
public class EmployeeDBHandler
{
    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
        string sqlConnstr = Utils.GetDBConnection();
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnstr);
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllEmployee", sqlConn);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlConn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var emp = new Employee()
                {
                    EId = (int)(reader["EmpID"]),
                    FirstName = (reader["FirstName"] != DBNull.Value && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(reader["FirstName"]))) ? Convert.ToString(reader["FirstName"]) : string.Empty,
                    LastName = (reader["LastName"] != DBNull.Value && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(reader["LastName"]))) ? Convert.ToString(reader["LastName"]) : string.Empty,
                };
                empList.Add(emp);
            }
        }
        return empList;
    }
}
```

- Check that you are getting proper data in empList or not.if you are getting proper data in empList then That is css issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response..data are getting in empList. The is a CSS issue..but difficult to find out how it occurs.